# Swift 3 - Saving an image change RGB values

Tags: image, swift3, rgba, steganography

I'm developing an application that hides the text using steganography method called LSB, putting it into the image. But during testing I found that when you save an image in the gallery and then load it from there, it's RGB values have changes. This is the red values:

```
34 -> 41
29 -> 34
44 -> 46
63 -> 62
101 -> 105
118 -> 119
```

Left - what they were, right - what they become. Of course such a change completely destroys the text hidden inside. This is the code I'm using to save an image:

```
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImg, self, #selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)


 func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saving error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Saved!", message: "Saved to the gallery", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

And this is the way I'm extracting RGB values:

```
func pixelData(image: UIImage) -> [UInt8]? {
    let size = image.size
    let dataSize = size.width * size.height * 4
    var pixelData = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(dataSize))
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let context = CGContext(data: &pixelData,width: Int(size.width), height: Int(size.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * Int(size.width), space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipLast.rawValue)
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return nil }
    context?.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))

    return pixelData
}
```

I need a way to save the image exactly as it is. Any help?

Edit 1. Text to image injection func:

```
func encrypt(image: UIImage, message: String) -> UIImage {

        var text = message
        text += endSymbols   //Need to decrypt message


        var RGBArray = pixelData(image: image)!
        let binaryMessage = toBinary(string: text) //Convert characters to binary ASCII number
         var counter: Int = 0

        for letter in binaryMessage {
            for char in letter.characters {

                let num = RGBArray[counter]
                let characterBit = char
                let bitValue = UInt8(String(characterBit))
                let resultNum = (num & 0b11111110) | bitValue!
                RGBArray[counter] = resultNum
                counter += 4 //Modify only RED values bits 
            }
        }

        let resultImg = toImage(data: RGBArray, width: Int(image.size.width), height: Int(image.size.height))
        return resultImg!
    }
```

Comment: When you save the image, is it in a JPEG format?

Comment: Yes, I tested it on my .jpg photos and on Apple's default images from gallery on Simulator

Comment: You can't use jpg photos with LSB substitution, because the image format is lossy (pixels can be modified during storage to achieve compression). Use bmp, png or any other lossless format instead.

Comment: I tried to use .png image, but still the same result. Did iOS automatically convert images to .jpg while saving it to photo library?

Comment: It's possible. Can you show the exact code you're using to save the image? If you can read the bytestream of the saved file, does it start with the bytes `ff d8 ff e0` (jpg) or `89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a` (png)?

Comment: I don't know how can I read bytestream but I added the code I'm using to encrypt

Comment: You need to save in an uncompressed format.

Comment: **I need a way to save the image exactly as it is. Any help?**

Seriously?

Comment: Can you post the code for ```toImage()```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save in an uncompressed format. I don't know how to programme in swift 3. I have solved the same questions in Objective-c using ALAssetsLibrary.

Comment: This is an unhelpful answer, suited more as a comment. The need to save to an uncompressed format has already been pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am a newcomer and practicing to answer the question . I would be careful next time.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know how it works but it works. 
I added this before saving encrypted picture:

```
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(encryptedImg)
        encryptedImg = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
```

Maybe this is an explicit specifier saving in .PNG .

Anyway the problem is solved.

Comment: Can you post the decrypt part?